# Is there a way to make bigger the characters of xterm?

Tags: 14.04, xterm

Is there a way to make bigger the characters of xterm? Where can I access the properties of xterm and change their configurations?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the properties of `xterm` and change their configurations:

By holding down the `Control` key upon your keyboard and clicking upon the body of the window with either your `left`, `right`, or `center` mouse button.

## So to change the the font size:

Press the `Control` key with one hand, and click the `right` mouse button.

*A menu appears, with the following font alternatives:*

```
Default (fontdefault)
     Set the font  to  the  default,  i.e.,  that given by the *VT100.font resource.
Unreadable (font1)
     Set   the   font   to   that  given  by  the *VT100.font1 resource.
Tiny (font2)
     Set  the  font  to   that   given   by   the *VT100.font2 resource.
Small (font3)
     Set   the   font   to   that  given  by  the *VT100.font3 resource. 
 Medium (font4)
     Set  the  font  to   that   given   by   the *VT100.font4 resource.
Large (font5)
     Set   the   font   to   that  given  by  the *VT100.font5 resource. 
Huge (font6)
     Set  the  font  to   that   given   by   the *VT100.font6 resource.
```

Answer (score -3):

If you are using gnome-terminal

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> to make text larger

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to make text smaller

Comment: This is not what he asked.